Copy text selection from one doc to another doc with python-docx
I have some 2000+ Word documents, each of them consists of different parts with titles, followed by either text, tables, etc. The titles can be distinguished by keywords.
So each document is "title with keyword one, text; title with keyword 2, table; title with keyword 3, another text".
I want to collect all the text belonging to a title with keyword one in a single, new document.
What I fail to accomplish: Find and select the part of the document from one title with keyword to the next. (it's actually not a paragraph from docx, and it does not really follow a unique formatting over all documents)
Can anyone be of help here? Does something like that exist?
